# Opening a new terminal from the command line and running a command on Mac OS X 10.10?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-yosemite, applescript

So I want to run a script, that launch when I log in, in a new terminal and print in a few line.

Do I need AppleScript as for what I've read so far ? Is there not a simple bash command to run this ?

I've seen that I could do it with Automator too but the old answers are outdated and I don't find the proper way to run a script from it; is this an old retire feature?

Answer (score 1):

### Run a script at login on OS X

OS X can run scripts and applications at login. The procedure is simple.

1. Open `System Preferences->Users & Groups`.
2. Select a user from the list at the left.
3. Click the `Login Items` tab.
4. Drag a script or application to the login items, or click the <kbd>+</kbd> icon to use Finder to locate the script.
5. Close `Users & Groups`.

Here's a sample script that can say "hello world" at login.

```
#!/bin/sh
say "Hello, world!"
exit
```

Save the file as text. Use Terminal to run `chmod u+x` to add execute permission to the script. Add the script to login items.

To stop the script from running at login, delete it from the `Login Items` tab.